# Check a field value in a array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a json which has a array structure like below

```
{
  "Opportunity": {
    "Contacts": {
      "QuotePreparedBy": "Ben Romoli",
      "Contact": {
        "FirstName": "abc",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "def",
        "Email": "abc@def.edu"
      },
      "Contact": {
        "FirstName": "xyz",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "lmn",
        "Email": "xyz@lmn.edu"
      },
      "Contact": {
        "FirstName": "bca",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "fed",
        "Email": "bca@fed.edu"
      }
    }
}
```

I have stored the entire payload in a variable called `inputPayload` I am retrieving the each Contact like

```
vars.inputPayload.Opportunity.Contacts.Contact
```

I have a requirement to check if the any of the contact email is `abc@def.edu` and then do a step. I wanted know how to check email of all the Contact in the choice set, should I just loop through every contact and check if the email address matches `abc@def.edu`

Any help is great appreciated

Comment: Your JSON has duplicate keys, which is not allowed. Please fix that. Your use case might be a simple [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) but I can't do anything before you fix the JSON.

Comment: This is the JSON structure that is generated converting a XML to JSON. Can I use the find if the JSON has duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use find as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Opportunity.Contacts.*Contact.Email find "abc@def.edu"
```

The output for this would be the location where the match is found which would be [0] since this email address occurs as the first match in the array (generated using `payload.Opportunity.Contacts.*Contact.Email`)  of Emails.

Answer (score 0):

```
<foreach collection="#[inputPayload]">
    <choice>
        <when expression="#[inputPayload.Email == 'abc@def.edu']">
            //found, do something
        </when>
        <otherwise>
          //not found, do something
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</foreach>
```

Comment: Thank you.. Is that not possible without a for loop?

Comment: you can also use the find method https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.2/dw-core-functions-find

Comment: In this case i don't think so, unfortunately. Because you need to iterate with each email key of your array

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a valid JSON. You can do this directly with XML as well.

You can add following Dataweave expression to the Choice/When

```
(vars.inputPayload.Opportunity.Contacts.*Contact.Email default []) contains "abc@def.edu"
```